webshot::webshot() is leaving dangling file connections behind. Why is that and how do I automatically close them?
If I use webshot::webshot() in the code of an R package function for which I supply a runnable example in the roxygen2 header, I get an Error (during R CMD check) similar to this:
Error: connections left open:
    /tmp/... (fifo)
    /tmp/... (fifo)
Execution halted

I can reproduce the dangling connections outside of the package context like this:
showConnections(all = TRUE)

  description class      mode text   isopen   can read can write
0 "stdin"     "terminal" "r"  "text" "opened" "yes"    "no"     
1 "stdout"    "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
2 "stderr"    "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    

Sys.setenv(OPENSSL_CONF = "/dev/null") # required depending on OS
webshot::webshot("https://github.com/rstudio/shiny") # webshot 0.5.5
Sys.unsetenv("OPENSSL_CONF") # required depending on OS
showConnections(all = TRUE)

  description                      class      mode text   isopen   can read can write
0 "stdin"                          "terminal" "r"  "text" "opened" "yes"    "no"     
1 "stdout"                         "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
2 "stderr"                         "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
3 "/tmp/..."                       "fifo"     "w+" "text" "opened" "yes"    "yes"    
4 "/tmp/..."                       "fifo"     "w+" "text" "opened" "yes"    "yes"    

Why does webshot::webshot() do that and how do I automatically close them?

I am also experiencing this issue. However, I have not yet been able to reproduce outside the roxygen example context.
